# Añadir una hoja a un destino de Excel en SSIS

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Al momento de utilizar el Excel Destination Editor en SSIS, luego de establecer el nombre y formato del archivo destino, se pueden modificar datos de las hojas de excel haciendo click en "new" o "nueva" (como se ve en la imagen), sin embargo, cuando yo selecciono esa opción,la opción se cierra y soy enviado de nuevo al flujo de datos. ¿Alguien tuvo ese problema alguna vez?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Eliminé la etiqueta [tag:sql] debido a que la pregunta parece no tener relación con ella. Por favor usa las etiquetas del sitio adecuadamente, pues son utilizadas no solo para organizar la información sino para atraer a las personas que consideran que pueden ayudarte, según su expertís y experiencia. Un saludo.